# How to make QtCreator show "normal" code while debugging instead of assembly?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator

I am using QtCreator 3.6.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 with gcc as my main compiler.

My Qt project is being built in debug mode. However, whenever I press F5, to try to step into the code by setting break points, my code crashes (since the code is buggy) but instead of stopping at the breakpoint, it shows me assembly output!

Here is a screen shot. The code seems to have crashed at where you see the yellow arrow, but I just don't know where in the source code it is!!!

[image]

In fact, I have set my breakpoint at a cout statement as you can see here.

[image]

Not even the `cout` statement is executing. The code seems to be crashing before main is executed.  I don't know if this is QtCReator problem or something else. I have added `-O0` and `-g` option 
to the QMAKE_CXXFLAGS option just to be sure, that debugging symbols are being added, yet I get this problem.

EDIT: 
My stack trace looks like this

[image]

Also I am not sure if this helps, but when I run the program through the terminal with `LD_DEBUG` in front of the program's name, I get a huge amount of output.

The last three lines are

```
.
.
.
      7934: symbol=_ZN11QMetaObject8addGuardEPP7QObject;  lookup in file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4 [0]
      7934: symbol=_ZN11QMetaObject8addGuardEPP7QObject;  lookup in file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4 [0]
      7934: binding file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4 [0] to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4 [0]: normal symbol `_ZN11QMetaObject8addGuardEPP7QObject'
[1]    7934 segmentation fault (core dumped)  LD_DEBUG=all ./CGALQT_Fix_MainWindow
```

Comment: Are you sure it crashes in your code? If it crashes in another library (libc, for example) where no debug information is available, it will still show assembly for those frames no matter if your code has full debug information or not. What does the full backtrace look like?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I see. Could you tell me how to get the full backtrace in QtCreator? I am not really sure what that is.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I don't know if it is crashing *in* my code. Not even the `cout` statement I placed as the first line of the code is being executed

Comment: It's listed in the area at the bottom, with lots of call_init() in it. I think there's a context menu option to copy the content. Do you have any global variables where it might crash initializing them?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Okay, please see edited question in which I have placed the stack trace at the very end. I don't have any global variables in my code. But as you said it is not crashing *in* my code...but some `dl-init.c` file. Not sure what that file is.  What is crash initializing?

Comment: should have read "where it might crash while initializing them", i.e. if you have some global/static initialization somewhere which is executed even before main() is entered.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld No I don't have any global / static variables. I have posted the last three lines of the output of `LD_DEBUG=all ./<program-name>` . Could that help in detecting the source of the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to create a small test case that does nothing else but shows a single `QLabel` from its `main`? Can you properly debug that?

Answer (score 0):

for this, your application has to link to debug libraries. To investigate where your app crashes, you don't usually need this because you can see all of your own methods in function stack.